# Splash-screen approach in single Activity app

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin, architecture, splash-screen

I am trying to decide on the best approach for creating an app splash-screen while taking into consideration Google's latest recommendations on choosing a single Activity app whenever possible.

See here:

["The new approach is to use one-activity structure whenever possible."](https://android.jlelse.eu/develop-your-android-app-in-a-modern-way-google-i-o-18-tips-8e064bbf0dd9)

and here:

["Today we are introducing the Navigation component as a framework for structuring your in-app UI, with a focus on making a single-Activity app the preferred architecture."](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/use-android-jetpack-to-accelerate-your.html?m=1)

Any good splash-screen approaches I have found have a dedicated Activity for the splash screen:

[See here](https://android.jlelse.eu/the-best-way-to-create-a-splash-screen-in-android-16f9096bf827)

[and here](https://android.jlelse.eu/right-way-to-create-splash-screen-on-android-e7f1709ba154)

Has anyone else had any experience creating a splash screen in a single Activity app? Does the the single Activity recommendation include the splash-screen or is it a special case? Does anyone have any good examples or advice on this?

Cheers,
Paul.

Comment: I personally think a splash screen doesn't fit the single activity app. It will bring too much logic for a x seconds print at start.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The approach I use is the following:

First define a drawable for the background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/green"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

2. Define a new style to use in the splashScreen:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

3. Make your activity implement use the splash theme:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

4. In on create, before the super invocation and before the set content view set the default app theme:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    setTheme(android.R.style.AppTheme)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

This approach is the one I've been using even with multiple Activities, since it follows the guidelines laid down by google: itshows the splash right away and doesn't stay longer than needed.

Comment: Thanks! this is the way I will go! I also found this same answer here not long after posting: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time under the section "Themed launch screens"

Comment: thanks but one question. if there are some activities except Main Activity. if the user comes back to Main Activity , is this theme shown again ? or it is shown for first time app launched.

Comment: I really depends on how the activities are launching and how you are getting to the MainActivity. I would recommend making a small sample project to test your particular use case and see if the results are what you expect

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ConstraintLayout` in your layouts, you can use the `Group` class of Android to group multiple views. Please refer to the following link for more information.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Group

This class controls the visibility of a set of referenced widgets. Widgets are referenced by being added to a comma separated list of ids, e.g:

```
 <android.support.constraint.Group
          android:id="@+id/group"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:visibility="visible"
          app:constraint_referenced_ids="button4,button9" />
```

FYI - Multiple groups can reference the same widgets -- in that case, the XML declaration order will define the final visibility state (the group declared last will have the last word).

Hope this helps you resolve the issue.

Comment: how is this relevant to the question?