# Splash approach in single activity shows everywhere splash theme

Tags: android, kotlin, themes, splash-screen

I use this approach in my single activity app - [Splash-screen approach in single Activity app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52835697/splash-screen-approach-in-single-activity-app)
But everywhere in my layouts I see splash theme and this prevents me from working with views in Android Studio.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Showing splash in single activity makes sense to me. Thank you for asking this question. I was looking for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android 12 now has a SplashScreen API, which enables a new app launch animation for all apps when running on a device with Android 12 or higher. This includes an into-app motion at launch, a splash screen showing your app icon, and a transition to your app itself, and for that, you don't need a Splash Activity.

As for your app, you need to set the theme only for SplashActivity. For other activity, set the theme to be the default one.

Comment: But I want that my app has only one activity. What can I do with it?

Comment: Thanks, I found the way https://proandroiddev.com/splashscreen-api-android-12-part-1-b2272e0ae98e

Comment: So the answer was to set the postSplashScreenTheme in the SplashScreen theme?